# Save initialized tensorflow graph from Keras

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a Tensorflow model in Keras, initialize it, and then save it so I can use it later in C++. I don't want to train it with Keras, because I have a custom training method in C++ that I want to use.

I tried to do this with:

```
def reset_weights(model):
    session = K.get_session()
    for layer in model.layers:
        if hasattr(layer, 'kernel_initializer'):
            layer.kernel.initializer.run(session=session)


inputs = Input(shape=(2,), name="inputs")
hidden_l = Dense(5, activation='relu', name="hidden_1", kernel_initializer="glorot_normal")(inputs)
hidden_l = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3, name="hidden_leakyrelu_1")(hidden_l)
outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name="outputs", kernel_initializer="glorot_normal")(hidden_l)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

reset_weights(model)
K.set_learning_phase(0)
sess = K.get_session()
f = "graph_def_for_reference.pb.ascii"
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), "./", f, as_text=True)
```

But the `graph_def_for_reference.pb.ascii` file still seems to contain a bunch of initialization nodes, rather than just the graph structure.

How can I run the initialization and save the graph and the initialized weights so I can then load them in TensorFlow C++?

Comment: If you `model.predict` with dummy data that should run the entire graph including initialisation. Then you can extract save the weights, I know you can `model.save` but not sure if you can load that into TensorFlow.

Comment: Unfortunately even after running model.predict, tf.train.write_graph still saves the graph with all the initialization nodes in it

Answer (score 0):

TF graphs contain all sorts of nodes which are never executed in a single call to session.run. The initialization nodes will always be there, but you do not have to run them.

To do what you want, though, I recommend you look into the tf savedmodel libraries, which let you save a graph, some variables, and a set of signatures so your C++ code can know what values to pass to session.run to get training to work.